# Автоматический merge в Stash после approved pull request

Tags: jenkins, git-stash

Имеется связка: Jenkins-Stash.
Процесс:

1. разработчик делает свою задачу в своей ветке (напирмер feature/some-1)
2. создает pull-request в stash
3. назначанет на ревью.

после этого:

1. jenkins собирает build и пишет успешно не успешно
2. ревьювер делает approved

и вот настал момент merge, когда разработчику необходимо и нажать эту кнопу, что бы подлить изменения в главную ветку.
Возможно этот процесс автоматизировать. т.е. если есть успешный build и approved, делать merge автоматом.

Comment: Это не совсем ответ на ваш вопрос, но в Github и Gitlab кнопки "ревью пройдено" и "сделать мерж" — это одна кнопка. А вы какой сервер гита используете?

Comment: используем продукт от atlassian stash как репозиторий.